How to create and retrieve the AWS RDS secret with Terraform
I would like to create an AWS RDS secret via Terraform (just the username and password, no rotation or KMS):
Here is everything I have so far, could you please review and let me know what I have done wrong? Thank you
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "db-secret" {
  name = "db-secret"
  description = "This is the db secret"
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
  force_overwrite_replica_secret = true
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["name"]
  }
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "db-secret_version" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.db-secret.id
  secret_string =  jsonencode({ "password" = "thisismypassword" })
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds" {
  secret_id  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.db-secret.id
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.db-secret]
}

locals {
  creds = jsondecode(
    data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.creds.secret_string
  )
}

Then this is how I use it in my lambda function:
DB_PASS = locals.creds.password


I tried deleting it via Terraform destroy but it cannot find the resource to delete, I am using the same state file:
terraform apply -destroy -target="aws_secretsmanager_secret.db-secret" --var-file mystatefile.tfvars


Based on your defined secret:
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "test_db_secret" {
  name = "test-db-secret"
}

You need to add a secret version and secret version data. Decode the output value:
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "test_db_secret_version" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.test_db_secret.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({ "password" = "thisismypassword" })
}


data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds" {
  secret_id  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.test_db_secret.id
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.test-db-secret]
}

locals {
  creds = jsondecode(
    data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.creds.secret_string
  )
}

and then you can pass that to your variable:
DB_PASS = locals.creds.password

You can see more examples in Terraform documentation

Thank you so much, I will give that a try. The resource definition above (in my post) doesn't work, could you please have a look at that one too? I guess I will have to remove the password line from there and just create a resource with name, then another resource block with version which we define the password

@Tina I edited the answer. Added the definition of secret version where you define your password. Also, corrected the secret_id in the creds section of my answer

thank you for your comment, I am getting an error on the DB_PASS line:
local.creds is a string, can't access attributes on a primitive-types value (string)

Please disregard, I had jsonencode instead of decode, trying it now

I am getting an error: The operation failed because the secret "secretname here" already exists. I even added recovery_window_in_days = 0 and force_overwrite_replica_secret = true but that didn't help

Did you delete the secret before adding the recovery window? It might be in the state of still waiting to be removed

Not sure how to do that, I tried deleting it via Terraform destroy but it cannot find the resource to delete, I am using the same state file:
terraform apply -destroy -target="aws_secretsmanager_secret.db-secret" --var-file mystatefile.tfvars

Here is everything I have so far, could you please review and let me know what I have done wrong? Thank you

Updated my question and wrote everything I have so far in my code. Could you please review and let me know what I did wrong? Thank you

It's possible that you tried deleting it before you added the recovery_window and thus that it's still waiting to be deleted in AWS. Can you try changing the secret name and see if that works for you? You shouldn't have an issue then

Yes, even though I gave the secret a new name, after running terraform apply I get an error: ResourceExistException: The operation failed because the secret already exists.
